# Did this character actually die in Chapter 4?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, sequels, john-wick-chapter-4

I've recently watched [*John Wick: Chapter 4*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10366206/), but I can't really understand the end. Did

> John Wick

really die? Why though? Couldn't they take him to the hospital, and probably he would live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's left deliberately vague.

> In a new interview with Empire, however, franchise director Chad Stahelski revealed that fans nearly saw a much different conclusion to the franchise's fourth installment, one in which Wick survived his epic ordeal.
>
> "We had a different ending," says the filmmaker. "[The theatrical ending] was the ending Keanu and I wanted, but we shot a different ending. We shot an ending where you actually saw John Wick at the end of the movie. So it was very clear that he was still alive. The audiences we tested with absolutely preferred the ambiguous ending."
>
> [source](https://ew.com/movies/john-wick-4-ending-keanu-reeves/#:%7E:text=We%20shot%20an%20ending%20where,absolutely%20preferred%20the%20ambiguous%20ending.%22)